# Is there a Spring MVC compatible UI Framework out there?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, user-interface, pagination

I am recently learning Spring MVC, and i am impressed how easy that is to achieve some common things like **Pagination**. For example i have a controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showAllItems")
public String showAllItems(Model model, Pageable pageable) {

    model.addAttribute("itemPage", itemService.getAllItems(pageable));

    return ViewNamesHolder.SHOW_ALL_ITEMS;
}
```

While Spring incredibly supports us at the backend by creating this pageable object, as far as i know there isn't any UI Framework which supports this kind of Spring objects at the frontend. After writing this perfect simple Controller method, we are again all alone on the frontend side, about how this pageable object will be displayed.

For example there is **Bootstrap**. Beautiful interface, very nice features. This article is a very nice example of how you can integrate Spring MVC with Bootstrap: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/implement-bootstrap-pagination-with-spring-data-and-thymeleaf.html

The problem is, we still have to write a lot of code. This is the jsp example from the above article, which at the end produces just a **pagination bar**:

```
<!-- Pagination Bar -->
<div th:fragment='paginationbar'>
  <div class='pagination pagination-centered'>
    <ul>
      <li th:class='${page.firstPage}? 'disabled' : '''>
        <span th:if='${page.firstPage}'>← First</span>
        <a th:if='${not page.firstPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page.page=1,page.size=${page.size})}'>← First</a>
      </li>
      <li th:class='${page.hasPreviousPage}? '' : 'disabled''>
        <span th:if='${not page.hasPreviousPage}'>«</span>
        <a th:if='${page.hasPreviousPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page.page=${page.number-1},page.size=${page.size})}' title='Go to previous page'>«</a>
      </li>
      <li th:each='item : ${page.items}' th:class='${item.current}? 'active' : '''>
        <span th:if='${item.current}' th:text='${item.number}'>1</span>
        <a th:if='${not item.current}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page.page=${item.number},page.size=${page.size})}'><span th:text='${item.number}'>1</span></a>
      </li>
      <li th:class='${page.hasNextPage}? '' : 'disabled''>
        <span th:if='${not page.hasNextPage}'>»</span>
        <a th:if='${page.hasNextPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page.page=${page.number+1},page.size=${page.size})}' title='Go to next page'>»</a>
      </li>
      <li th:class='${page.lastPage}? 'disabled' : '''>
        <span th:if='${page.lastPage}'>Last →</span>
        <a th:if='${not page.lastPage}' th:href='@{${page.url}(page.page=${page.totalPages},page.size=${page.size})}'>Last →</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This JSP page is then reusable thanks to the author. But still we need frameworks which handles this kind of things automatically, that is what i call Spring MVC Compatible. And this should seem sth like this on the frontend, which handles the pagination almost automatically:

```
<div springUI:fragment='paginationbar' springUI:object='itemPage'/>
```

Maybe with some additional attributes like firstAndLastButtonsVisible or currentPageDisabled etc..

For the above example, since we have every info we need (pageCount etc.) in the object *itemPage*, this simplicity (or almost) is possible.

Now my question again, is there a very Spring MVC compatible UI Framework out there?

Comment: If it was that easy wouldn't all the script kiddies have our jobs?

Comment: This website is not for recommending libraries or tools. But if you can't find any, why not invent your own JSP tags to handle pagination?

Comment: I have already created one. It just sounds strange to me, having so many creative libraries at the banckend, which does not have any influence on the frontend. In the future we sure will have sth like above example. Maybe we already have. If we already have, i would like to know where. In addition, my question is about "Spring MVC Compatible UI Framework", not the pagination itself. It was just an example of what i mean. As i said, i have the pagination now, but in the future i will sure have similar needs about this kind of spring objects, which i would like to use on the frontend too.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're looking for such approach - [Rich Web Application with Spring MVC CRUD demo](http://blog.zkoss.org/index.php/2015/11/17/rich-web-application-with-spring-mvc-crud-demo/)

In that article, it used Spring MVC controller to work with ZK UI components seamlessly.

Comment: wow, that's a pretty awesome and new article. I have been used Spring MVC + JSP + JQuery to build a CMS backend and finally got a mess result. the code from client js and jsp generated js confused other newbie in my team. so i think it's a good idea to prevent from getting mess.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at spring roo (http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/). It use some kind of self written jsp based tag library.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Pay attention to the `*.tagx` files

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Displaytag](http://www.displaytag.org). You will need to wrap your list&Pageable in an implementation of `org.displaytag.pagination.PaginatedList`. However this is pretty much all you need as "bridge" between displaytag and spring.